# How to put prefix on expressions surrounded by curly brackets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

What could be the javascript regex expression of putting prefix to all values in angular curly braclets ?

```
//prefix : listItem
//before
<span>{{name}} {{surname}}</span>
//after
<span>{{listItem.name}} {{listItem.surname}}</span>
```

Comment: you should change your object structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(\w+)(?=\}\})/g` to match word followed by `}}`

```js
var span = document.querySelector("span");
span.textContent = span.textContent.replace(/(\w+)(?=\}\})/g, function(match) {
  return "listItem." + match
})
```

```html
<span>{{name}} {{surname}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
"<span>{{name}} {{surname}}</span>".split("{{").join("{{listItem.")
```

returns : `"<span>{{listItem.name}} {{listItem.surname}}</span>"`